# Visual studio 2017: изменяется background image после запуска приложения

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

Изменяется background image после запуска приложения.
(background image задаю средствами VS(в свойствах), после чего делаю запуск.)
В конструкторе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После запуска:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, кто знает, в чём проблема ?

Comment: При чем тут VS17 и какая платформа используется (WinForms или WPF)?

Comment: WinForms,
"При чем тут VS17"  - а в чём проблема ?)

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы задаете вопрос так, будто это косяк студии, когда на самом деле это все связано с WinForms и его обработкой изображения. Итог - метка лишняя, вопрос не понятен, кода нет, нет нечего...

Comment: background image задаю средствами VS(в свойствах), после чего делаю запуск.

Comment: Ну так это все должно быть указано в вопросе, а не так, что мы гадаем тут...

Comment: Добавил, спасибо за указку)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение!)
Нужно добавить в program.cs пару строк с настройкой.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e